# Unable to load antd less styles

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, less, antd

I have NextJs project with following structure

```
-pages
    -_app.tsx
-app
    -styles
        -antdstyles.less
```

inside `_app.tsx` i am trying to load `import '@styles/andstyles.less` which simply imports  antd styles ass this `@import '~antd/dist/antd.less'`;
However i get error saying

/app/styles/antdstyles.less

@import '~antd/dist/antd.less';
^
'~antd/dist/antd.less' wasn't found. Tried - /home/computer/job/proj/app/styles/~antd/dist/antd.less,/home/computer/job/proj/css/~antd/dist/antd.less,/home/computer/job/proj/~antd/dist/antd.less,~antd/dist/antd.less

Answer (score 0):

you have to use less loader and config it in next.config.js of your project. it's not supported to use less in next app out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

you can try upgrading the antd version, Current version 5.* is working great for me.

Edit:
Antd is moved on from the less files in V5, and they have started using the css-in-js. Details from the antd about this is mentioned in the upgrade guide. ant.design/docs/react/migration-v5#technology-adjustment You'll have to remove all the less files and follow the steps mentioned in less file migration guide: ant.design/docs/react/migration-v5#less-migration

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @Kishan Virani

Comment: while updating the antd version to 5.11.3 then the files under the below import are not available "~antd/lib/style/themes/dark. Less";  "~antd/dist/antd.dark.less"      "~antd/lib/style/themes/default. Less";  where the alternative for these less in latest version?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Antd is moved on from the less files in V5, and they have started using the css-in-js. Details from the antd about this is mentioned in the upgrade guide. https://ant.design/docs/react/migration-v5#technology-adjustment

You'll have to remove all the less files and follow the steps mentioned in less file migration guide: https://ant.design/docs/react/migration-v5#less-migration